# Geting undefined when passing in a parameter to a Module pattern function

Tags: javascript, object

```
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
    amountItems.speek('heey')
})

var amountItems = (function(el) {
    // var el = el;
    return {
        speek: function() {
            alert(el)
        }
    }
}())
```

This is my first attempt to using a module pattern. basically when foo get's clicked i want the speek method inside the amountItems function to be called and I want to pass the string 'heey' to the method so it should alert 'heey' when foo is clicked. originally i wanted to pass something like $("#foo").text() but either way I get 'undefined'.

can you show me how to work with a jQuery object when it's passed into this type of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have the parameter for `el` in the wrong place.  This works:

```
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
    amountItems.speek('heey')
})

var amountItems = (function() {
    return {
        speek: function(el) {
            alert(el);
        }
    }
}())
```

--edit--

Just in case you were wondering how the whole scope / private variables thing works:

```
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
    amountItems.load('heey');
    amountItems.speek();
})

var amountItems = (function() {
    var el = ""

    return {
        load: function(str) {
            el = str;
        },
        speek: function() {
            alert(el);
        }
    }
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
var amountItems = (function(el) {
    // var el = el;
    return {
        speek: function() {
            alert(el)
        }
    }
}())
```

You execute a wrapper function and assign `amountItems` with the inner object.
You **don't** pass a param(`el`) when you invoke this and therefore `el` is undefined.

`amountItems` is an object with a method called `speek` that **doesn't** except params.

The **right** way to do this is:

```
var amountItems = {
        speek: function(txt) {
            alert(txt);
        }
    };

$("#foo").on("click", function() {
    amountItems.speek('heey')
})
```